# Use reflection to reset all dependency properties back to their default?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I know it is possible to use reflection to access all dependency properties on a given class. But is it possible to use reflection, or some other generic technique, to set all dependency properties back to the default value that was given when the property was registered?

example dp:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IdProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Id", typeof(int?), typeof(OwnerClass), new PropertyMetadata(0));
public int? Id { get { return (int?)GetValue(IdProperty); } }
```

Can I loop through all such dps in any given class and set them back to the value given by the original PropertyMetadata object?

My purpose is to try and create a "Clear()" method in an abstract base class for all viewmodels in a wpf application. I would like to give Clear() the default behavior of setting all dps that might be registered back to the default value given when registered. The user can override this behavior when/if needed.

Comment: Please clearly explain what you are trying to achieve by doing this... there *might* be a better way.

Comment: Yeah you can do that. Not enough info though. Basically to pass an instance, find the property(s), find the default and then call the setter on the property with the default value. Please tell me you don't want to do that from the getter though.

Comment: My purpose is to try and create a "Clear()" method in an abstract base class for all viewmodels in a wpf application. I would like to give Clear() the default behavior of setting all dps that might be registered back to the default value given when registered. The user can override this behavior when/if needed.

Comment: Any reason you are using dependency properties instead of INPC?

Comment: This may sound green, but no there is no reason except that dp is what I have been exposed to when dealing with wpf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be something like this:

using a simple model:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

A dependency object to clear it's properties

```
public class EmployeesDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EmployeesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Employees", typeof(ObservableCollection<Employee>), typeof(EmployeesDataGrid), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<Employee>()));

    public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Employee>)GetValue(EmployeesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EmployeesProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

use it in xaml:

```
<local:EmployeesDataGrid x:Name="myGrid"/>
```

I fill it in the code-behind (Just for example simplicity sake!) like this:

```
myGrid.Employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>
{
     new Employee { Age = 20, FirstName = "John"},
     new Employee { Age = 30, FirstName = "Alex"}
};
```

In the clear method:

```
foreach (FieldInfo field in depedencyObjectType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public))
{
     if (field.FieldType == typeof (DependencyProperty))
     {
          var dp = field.GetValue(depedencyObject) as DependencyProperty;
          depedencyObject.ClearValue(dp);
     }
}
```

`depedencyObject` is `myGrid`

`depedencyObjectType` is `depedencyObject.GetType()`

If you'll use the debugger to see the `Employees` property on `myGrid` it shows `Count = 0`.

Comment: Interesting. This works really well, except my observable collection does not seem to be affected. It shows that it calls ClearValue on it, but it keeps the elements of the collection. I have the PropertyMetadata set to new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<Details>()) so I would think it would reset.

Comment: @PriceJones that's weird, it seems to work fine for me ... hold on I'll update my answer with example code

Comment: I went ahead and checked this as the answer even though for some reason on my part I can't get the observable collection to work. Otherwise, though it is exactly what I need. Thanks.

Comment: @PriceJones were you able to make my code run? update your question with the full code of your collection so we can compare to see the differences